# What type of paradox kills Weeping Angels?

Tags: doctor-who, paradox, weeping-angels

I'm trying to find ways to defeat Angels beside simply getting them to look at each other. For instance, in the episodes “The Time of Angels” and “Flesh and Stone”, you can't get a large group of Angels to look at each other. I thought of using a mirror, but that's if someone is fast enough to smash all the mirrors to trap them before the Angels get to them. The only other option is **"paradox which would poison the time energy they used to feed."**

Comment: A mirror is used in *The Time of the Doctor*.

Comment: That's what I wanted to do, but I read somewhere you have to smash the mirrors in order to keep the angels in quantum lock. If you don't then the angels multiply. "An image of an angel, becomes an angel itself."

Comment: Well, you answered your own question. The only way to completely eliminate the Weeping angels is by a paradox; doesn't matter what kind of paradox it is.

Comment: Just bind them in chains while looking at them.. Done!

Comment: BTW, a mirror won't work because an image of an angel is an angel.

Comment: Would the mirror image not trap the angel because they are looking at each other.

Comment: Shreedhar: A mirror would work for a few angels, but in my story, the entire world is populated with them. There's no way for them to smash all the mirrors without getting caught by the other angels.

Comment: In the 'PROSE: Magic of the Angels' "The Doctor, Amy and Rory neutralized the Angel by making it make a duplicate of itself through its reflection on a mirror. After a brief panic of more Angels appearing, the mirror was smashed, leaving the two Angels in a quantum lock." A mirror is a canon way to destroy angels but it would still increase the problem if you can't smash the mirror in time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Angels can also be starved to death - they literally waste away, their forms decaying, looking like erosion. The time frame needed to do so in unknown.

The way they feed is somewhat unclear - in Blink, they feed off the potentiality of the person's "unlived" life in the present, but in Manhattan, it seems more like the people sent to the past are fed upon by Angels in that past, hence the building where their victims are held.

The implication in Manhattan is that the paradox must involve the person on whom the Angels are feeding / have fed. So by dying as a young person before he's captured, Rory negated the timeline where they trapped him, resulting in a paradox that did more than kill one Angel, it virtually erased almost all of the ones involved in the plan.

So the bootstrap paradox in Blink would not kill the Angel, as the events did not undo themselves.  If Sally had returned to the old house during the events of the first half of the story and directly interacted with her friend, telling her to turn around or some such, it may have, since it would have affected someone who was a victim of the Angels.

But then they'd probably have to deal with those guys from Father's Day...

Comment: Thank you, this explained so much about paradoxes and what to avoid. I needed for a story, and I wanted my book to be accurate.